# Minecraft Server Resource Pack Manager Application

Tags: java, zip, dropbox, minecraft, dropbox-api

fellow developers.

Let's imagine the following scenario: A group of friends is playing Minecraft on a server. That server has a *resource pack* associated (file **server.properties**, field **resource-pack**). That resource pack is a **ZIP** file hosted by **Dropbox**, and the respective **Dropbox** share link is what goes on field **resource-pack**.

All good, for now. *Resource pack* loads flawlessly.

However, those friends need to update the *resource pack* with their custom textures every now and then. I'd like to automate that process in the best way possible. To provide a custom texture, one needs 2 files: a **.png** file and a **.properties** file. Those are fairly easy to make. Then, those files need to be put in the following directory (**Dropbox**):

`/ResourcePack.zip/assets/minecraft/optifine/cit/`

The problem here is that the **Dropbox API** can't upload to existing ZIP files, and the *resource pack* has to be a **ZIP** file, int order for Minecraft to recognize it. Also, I don't want to download the ZIP file, extract, put the files inside, compress and upload again, because it's quite a large file and that would take some time.

My Java application looks like this:

[image]

What the application does now, is accept dragged files and send them to the Dropbox path:

`/ResourcePack/assets/minecraft/optifine/cit/`

But not:

`/ResourcePack.zip/assets/minecraft/optifine/cit/`

I was told the **Dropbox API** can't handle uploads to **ZIP** files, and I also can't find anything on the documentation [here](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/).

Can anyone think of a solution, other than downloading the full *resource pack*, and uploading it back everytime someone wants to add custom textures?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

So, as Adriaan suggested, I can simply use a direct link to the unzipped directory structure of the *resource pack*.

The problem is now another:

When a player joins the server, and downloads the *resource pack* for the first time ever, everything is fine. However, it gets cached in his local machine, in the following path:

`/.minecraft/server-resource-packs/`

So, when the *resource pack* is updated with new custom textures, minecraft will just load the cached *resource pack* and ignore any updates present in **Dropbox**. This results in the player not seeing the new custom textures.

I've learned about the [resource-pack-sha1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/4k4639/how_can_i_use_resourcepacksha1/) field in **server.properties**. It looks just like what I need, but I can't quite understand how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the unzipped directory structure. DropBox allows downloading a directory as a zip file.

You can force dropbox to do a direct download by changing the dl=0 at the end of the URL to dl=1 [see this help page](https://help.dropbox.com/nl-nl/files-folders/share/force-download)

Comment: I've tried that. Minecraft just says the *resource pack* couldn't be applied. Using that method, the Dropbox direct link to the *resource pack* actually downloads a **ZIP** file containing the correct files, which is strange. Minecraft doesn't recognize it, though.

Comment: Yep! I did that, but it just says "resource pack couldn't be applied".

Comment: Did you compare the zip file generated by dropbox against the one you upload yourself? Any differences in structure?

Comment: Maybe the files are nested one directory to deep? I just checked, it seems to put the files under a root directory with the same name as the zip

Comment: It's actually working now lol. I remember testing that and it didn't work. However, this now leads to another problem. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the remark on the page you linked is still true "This is not yet used to verify the integrity of the resource pack, but improves the effectiveness and reliability of caching." then you could just enter a random new value into **resource-pack-sha1** to trigger all clients to download the new pack.

If you need the actual digest then you could follow [this mini tutorial](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/2747027-mini-tutorial-creating-an-sha1-for-server)

> to generate an SHA1 for your server.properties:
>
> 1. visit this website: http://onlinemd5.com/
> 2. Upload your resourcepack
> 3. copy the SHA1 and paste it into your server.properties for the resource-pack-sha1 option
>
> all done!

If you don't want to upload your resource pack to someone else's server you could [download a tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html) to determine the digest locally.

Note: DropBox offers a [content hash](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/content-hash) via their API, but it's not an SHA1 over the complete file. Rather they split the file in 4 MB blocks and determine the SHA256 for each, concatenate them and SHA256 the result again. If there's a way to change the hashing algorithm used by Minecraft this could be used.

EDIT: Is it an option to rename the resource pack directory on DropBox when you change its contents? This will circumvent the caching and hashing issue. Clients will just need to change the resource pack URL accordingly.

Comment: Hm... The random number thing is actually a good idea. I will try that one out. However, to get the actual digest, I would have to download the *resource pack* from Dropbox, so that's out of question. Thank you, though!

Comment: Maybe it's time to split up the resource pack if it's so unwieldy large?